# Can I programmatically escape dashes in Sitecore queries using FullPath?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I'm attempting to expand upon a custom Sitecore command to determine if the current item has a parent item matching a certain template id.

I know the query should ideally be as simple as `./ancestor::*[@@templateid='{26710865-F082-4714-876B-D5E1F386792F}']` if the item is the context, or `/sitecore/content/home/full/path/to/the-item/ancestor::*[@@templateid='{26710865-F082-4714-876B-D5E1F386792F}']`

Unfortunately the item path includes dashes which need to be escaped like `/sitecore/content/home/full/path/to/#the-item#/ancestor::*[@@templateid='{26710865-F082-4714-876B-D5E1F386792F}']`.

However, ideally I'd like to just use the full path of the item, since it's available as `item.Paths.FullPath`.

Given an item, what's the best way to write a query containing it's full path, and escaping any dashes that might be contained within?

Comment: consider using `item.Axes.GetAncestors().Where(...)` to keep your code easy to understand and debug.

Comment: @zzzzBov do you mind creating this as an answer so that I can give you an upvote? I knew there was a way to access ancestors via something LINQ friendly, but I *always* forget about that dang `Axes` property.

Comment: @zzzzBov Since it doesn't appear the question has been asked already on SO, per the [meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322356/11912), I've posted [the question you answered](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37015538/11912) as a new question.

Comment: @JamesSkemp I was just wondering whether you've had time to test the approaches from mine and Marek's answers? I'm interested to know which approach you ended up using.

Comment: Neither, actually. Using LINQ/`Axes` is generally my preferred way, when I remember that the property exists. Between the two of you I'm not sure which solution is better, so I upvoted you both and will keep an eye on this to accept an answer once more votes have been given.

Answer (score 6):

I've never seen any Sitecore util class or any other out of the box code which does what you need. It's funny that Sitecore does have a util method which returns `false` (yes, it does return `false`) but doesn't have a method which escapes item path so it can be used in query.

You may find code which does what you want (written by Anders Laub) here: https://blog.istern.dk/2014/10/29/escaping-dashes-in-sitecore-queries-datasource-query-update/

And if you're too lazy to click the link, I've copied to code here:

```cs
private string EscapeItemNamesWithDashes(string queryPath)
{
  if (!queryPath.Contains("-"))
   return queryPath;

  var strArray = queryPath.Split(new char[] { '/' });
  for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++)
  {
    if (strArray[i].IndexOf('-') > 0)
    strArray[i] = "#" + strArray[i] + "#";
  }
  return string.Join("/", strArray);
}
```

If you want to escape also space character, you can try this regex:

```cs
string escapedPath = Regex.Replace(myItem.Paths.FullPath, "[^/]*[- ][^/]*", "#$0#");
```

Also you should remember that there are some reserved words in Sitecore which should be escaped as well. Those are (copied from http://www.newguid.net/sitecore/2012/escape-characterswords-in-a-sitecore-query/ ):

- ancestor
- and
- child
- descendant
- div
- false
- following
- mod
- or
- parent
- preceding
- self
- true
- xor

Comment: This code will surround `ancestor::*[...]` with hashes, which is probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: Hey @DmytroShevchenko the code I copied from Anders is only for escaping the item path, not the query.

Comment: Ah, got it. It'll work fine then. How about item names with white spaces? Are they optional to escape?

Comment: Good one. I think they are. Actually this regex should do the trick: `string escapedPath = Regex.Replace(myItem.Paths.FullPath, "[^/]*[- ][^/]*", "#$0#");`  (copied from https://sdn.sitecore.net/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?postid=29395 ). Still it does not take into account reserved words in sitecore. Answer updated.

Comment: Why not just escape all parts of the path is you're worried about bad characters or reserved words?

Answer (score 5):

### Assumptions

Assuming you have a reference to a `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item` (called `item`) and you would like to find an ancestor with a given `Sitecore.Data.ID` (called `id`), there are a number of ways you can access the ancestor.

### Using Linq

In a typical Sitecore setup without any custom libs, I would typically use a bit of Linq so as to avoid encoding issues in XPath.

```cs
ancestor =
    item
        .Axes
        .GetAncestors()
        .FirstOrDefault(ancestor => ancestor.TemplateID == id);
```

### Using `Closest`

I use a bespoke framework for Sitecore development that involves a wide variety of extension methods and customized item generation. To avoid the overhead of accessing *all* the ancestors before filtering, I would use the `Closest` extension method:

```cs
public static Item Closest(this Item source, Func<Item, bool> test)
{
    Item cur;
    for (cur = source; cur != null; cur = cur.Parent)
    if (test(cur))
        break;
    return cur;
}
```

Accessing the ancestor would then be:

```cs
ancestor =
    item
        .Closest(ancestor => ancestor.TemplateID == id);
```

(Actually, I typically use code that looks like)

```cs
ancestor = (ITemplateNameItem) item.Closest(Is.Type<ITemplateNameItem>);
```

### Using XPath

I usually avoid XPath and only use it as a tool of last resort because it often makes code harder to read, introduces encoding issues such as the one you're faced with in this question, and has a hard limit on the number of items that can be returned.

That said, Sitecore has many tools available for searching with XPath, and in some circumstances it *does* simplify things.

The trick to fixing item paths that contain spaces is: *Don't use item paths*.

Instead, you can safely use the item's ID, with no more context necessary because it's an absolute reference to the item. It's also guaranteed to follow a specific format.

```cs
var query =
    string.Format(
        "//{0}/ancestor::*[@@templateid='{1}']",
        item.ID.ToString(),
        id.ToString());
/* alternatively
var query =
    string.Format(
        "{0}/ancestor::*[@@templateid='{1}']",
        item.Paths.LongID,
        id.ToString());
*/
ancestor =
    item
        .Database
        .SelectSingleItem(query);
```

### Using `Sitecore.Data.Query.Query`

As I mentioned previously, Sitecore has *many* tools available for searching with XPath. One of these tools is `Sitecore.Data.Query.Query`. The `SelectItems` and `SelectSingleItem` methods have additional optional parameters, one of which is a `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item` as a `contextNode`.

Passing an item in as the second parameter uses the item as the context for the XPath query.

```cs
var query =
    string.Format(
        "./ancestor::*[@@templateid='{0}']",
        id.ToString());
ancestor =
    Sitecore
        .Data
        .Query
        .Query
        .SelectSingleItem(query, item);
```

Comment: Wow. Not only did you answer the question in a couple different ways, I think you also gave me the answer to the question I should have asked. I guess the only note is that `GetAncestors()` returns top-down, so if you want the closest ancestor to the item you'll have to order accordingly. I also either forgot or didn't know you could just dump in an item id in a query. Nice.

Comment: @JamesSkemp that *should* have been a separate question though. Now the approved answer does not answer the question you asked.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko, it's essentially an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and in the end the important point is: if you have to ask the question, you're probably looking for the wrong solution.

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunately, I think you're right, but this is also the answer to the question that I was trying to ask. My problem was "I'm attempting to expand upon a custom Sitecore command to determine if the current item has a parent item matching a certain template id." I'll see if a question on Meta covers this, and if not ask to see how if I should retroactively change the question, or switch the accepted answer.

Comment: @JamesSkemp, in the end it's your call which answer answered your question best. Votes are used so that visitors can decide which answer is best in aggregate. I wouldn't worry about it too much in this case so long as you make sure to upvote good answers that answered your question.

Comment: In this case, the question asked is valid in its own right. It will be useful to others in the future. I would actually remove extra context from the question and only leave the text relevant to escaping Sitecore Queries.

Comment: I can understand how relevant the question I ended up asking would be to others, since as far as I know this is only and best place to find an answer to the above question. So I've [asked on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322356/11912).

Comment: Meta has suggested that I post another question asking what I basically asked in my first paragraph, and accept as an answer what solves my asked question. Since both of the other answers that I've upvoted are, *as far as I currently know*, equal, I'll be holding off on accepting either until one gets ranked up higher, or after I've tested both options. My apologizes to all for the confusion, but I do greatly appreciate your time and solutions, especially since I genuinely believe these answers to be extremely beneficial.

Answer (score 3):

There's no public helper method in Sitecore that would escape Sitecore Query paths. You'll need to implement escaping logic by hand.

### Code-based approach:

I found some code in Sitecore.Kernel.dll, in the pipeline processor `Sitecore.Pipelines.GetLookupSourceItems.ProcessDefaultSource`. I had to rework it so that complex selectors containing `:` and `[...]` are not escaped:

```cs
static string EscapeQueryPath(string queryPath)
{
  string[] strArray = queryPath.Split('/');

  for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; ++i)
  {
    string part = strArray[i];

    if ((part.IndexOf(' ') >= 0 || part.IndexOf('-') >= 0)
        && part.IndexOf(':') == -1
        && part.IndexOf('[') == -1
        && !part.StartsWith("#", StringComparison.InvariantCulture)
        && !part.EndsWith("#", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
    {
      strArray[i] = '#' + part + '#';
    }
  }

  return string.Join("/", strArray);
}
```

Note that this algorithm:

- Is idempotent - it won't escape the parts of the path which have already been escaped, so `/#item-name#/` will not turn into `/##item-name##/`.
- Will escape item names that contain either hyphens or spaces.
- Takes into account complex selectors (like `ancestor::*[...]` in your example).

## Regex approach:

Here's another approach to escaping. It will have exactly the same results as the code above.

```csharp
string path = "./my-item/ancestor::*[@@templateid='{26710865-F082-4714-876B-D5E1F386792F}']";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, "/([^/#\\[\\:]*[- ][^/#\\[\\:]*(?=($|/)))", "/#$1#");
// result: ./#my-item#/ancestor::*[@@templateid='{26710865-F082-4714-876B-D5E1F386792F}']
```

This is shorter, but most likely a bit slower.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with previous answers but there are few more things which must be escaped for the queries - names with words 'or' & 'and' and words starting with numbers. I used code similar to this:

```
string _path = "/path/to-item/12name and qwe/test"; // your path
string[] pathParts = _path.Split(new[] {'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string escapedPath = string.Join("/", pathParts.Select(p =>
{
    if (p.Contains("and") || p.Contains("or") || p.Contains("-") || char.IsDigit(p[0]))
    {
        return "#" + p + "#";
    }
    return p;
}));
```